# Connection string to azure with android

Tags: android, azure-table-storage

I seen this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/
but i have problem with connection string when run app with android.

This is my connection:

```
    public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;"
        + "AccountName=demoeeg;"
        + "AccountKey=aDJtpWT2/UjBjrwt3BprpujNLNueTl5CjHkik6X6ELdLjGCU5jbnwXz8YCHnQs6wVO6YvY5sGUc7xWon/Iv3ug==";
```

and in other class I set:

```
private static final String USE_DEVELOPMENT_STORAGE_NAME = "UseDevelopmentStorage";
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set use development storage. This means use the storage emulator -- and that's not going to work with Android. I'd recommend checking out the samples in the [azure-storage-android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android) repo which will give you some ideas on how to configure your application. Then, you can pull any code snippets you'd like from the how-to which will also give you more conceptual information.

Comment: I did it with this sample and have this error. And I think  `use development storage` is not `USE_DEVELOPMENT_STORAGE_NAME`

Comment: Are you using the Android sample? In that case, where are you setting this variable? I don't believe it's present by default in those samples.

Comment: So what should i set `USE_DEVELOPMENT_STORAGE_NAME = ` This setting in class CloudStorageCloud.

Comment: I don't know where you're getting that var from. It's not in the android samples, and it's not in the how to, meaning it's specific to your application. If it's application specific, you're going to have to say what you're trying to do and give a more full code snippet along with what's not working.

Comment: Solved. This sample work with kitkat api 19 but i run it with lolipop api 21. Thanks for your help.